# На компьютере в эксплорере 11, с мобильным юзерагентом,на странице авито, номер телефона не показывается?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

Все настройки вроде включил, а номер не показывает.В мазиле,хром нормально.
Нужен именно эксплорер.

Меняю в реестре пуск-regedit-
http://HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\ User Agent\

Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:40.0) Gecko/40.0 Firefox/40.0

ссылка https://m.avito.ru/..........

Comment: Наверное из-за того что тип вашего устройства определяется не только по агенту в совокупности?

Comment: Если yandex.ru/internet не определяет реальный юзер,то авито тем более.